# How to estabilish a secure connection on localhost with angular dart webdev?

Tags: angular, https, dart, angular-dart

I'm using angular dart to build a web application, and when it comes to accessing user location feature such as geolocation, browsers like chrome enforce https.
When I deploy the web application the location api works because the connection is secure, but when I debug on localhost it is broken because (I assume) of the unsecure session.

Is there a way to configure the webdev generated http server to use somehow a self signed ssl certificate?

Is there any viable alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `--tls-cert-chain` and `--tls-cert-key` flags were just added to `webdev serve`. I used this tutorial for setting up the cert and key: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-get-https-working-on-your-local-development-environment-in-5-minutes-7af615770eec/.

Then the following command served up the app at `https://127.0.0.1:8080`

`webdev serve --release --tls-cert-chain path-to-cert/server.crt --tls-cert-key path-to-key/server.key`

The changes are in webdev 2.5.0.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I got this error `Could not find an option named "tls-cert-chain".` I am using webdev 2.3.0.
This is my cmd: 
`webdev serve --tls-cert-chain path/server.crt --tls-cert-key path/server.key`

Can not find any error

Comment: Worked after upgraded  webdev  to 2.5.0.

Comment: Thanks, I added the version.